# How to sort a character vector numerically based on a trailing digit in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector

`x = c("E1","E2","E4","E4","E5","E6","E10","I1","I2","I4","I12")`

I need to sort that in a way the output should be

`x = c("E1","I1","E2","I2","E4","E4","I4","E5","E6","E10","I12")`

but when I use `sort(x)` it gives

`c("E1","E10","E2","E4","E4","E5","E6","I1","I12","I2","I4")\`

Is there anyway I could sort them as I wanted above?

Comment: Interesting question. For questions related to programming, such as this one, have a look at stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, the data vector is already alphabetically sorted. Therefore, the function

```
custom.sort <- function(x){x[order(as.numeric(substring(x, 2)))]}
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

An easy and generic way to achieve this is to use the function mixedsort from the package gtools
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gtools/docs/mixedsort

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you will be doing often you might consider writing a method for   the xtrfm function.  You can use regular expressions to split the strings and order with multiple columns to det the ordering right.

You might also want to look at the mixedsort function in the gtools package to see if that works for you (or you could use it as a base and modify the code if it does not work as is).